# Нажать на тег button  в WebBrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Подскажите, как нажать на кнопку такого вида из Webbrowser в Delphi:

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

Нужно именно нажать на эту кнопку. Нужно что-то вроде этого.

```
procedure TForm1.btnclick(btnname: string);
var
  ovElements: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ovElements := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.item(0).elements;
  for i := 0 to (ovElements.Length - 1) do
    if (ovElements.item(i).tagName = 'button') and
      (ovElements.item(i).type = 'submit') and
      (ovElements.item(i).value = btnname) then
      ovElements.item(i).Click;
end;
```

Только не для `<imput type="submit">`, a для кнопки с содержимым. Проблема исчерпана. Обошелся без кнопки, отправил данные в PostData функцией

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate2(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers);
```

Comment: Ну, так а в чем проблема? Из копипаста нужно удалить условный блок:

    (ovElements.item(i).value = btnname)

И первая найденная кнопка `<button type="submit">` в первой форме будет нажата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всей видимости, вам нужно не нажать на кнопку, а отловить событие нажатия. Прямого обработчика нажатий у WebBrowser-а нет. Для этой цели, можно воспользоваться обработчиком `OnBeforeNavigate2`. Он отлавливает переход с одной страницы на другую.

Для начала нужно `button` положить в `form`-контейнер:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Теперь, в результате нажатия на кнопку браузер попытается сменить страницу на ту, что указана в атрибуте `action`. Этот переход можно перехватить обработчиком:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowserBeforeNavigate2(Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
```

С помощью `Cancel := True` переход можно запретить. Это даст возможность обработать нажатие  и остаться на той-же странице.